# How to embed a small external webapp in an iframe?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iframe, embed

I have a .net application that needs to call an other external web app. This external web app is also a ASP.NET MVC app that returns one fully functional view. This means it returns a view that has a few textboxes and radio buttons and a submit button.

When I call this webapp from the first webapp, it shows he view inside it and so on. I am not sure how do I submit the form to the external web app. Because isn't it that it will check for cross site scripting and deny the request? How to overcome that?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use partial view for that purpose. You can not access controls from iframe in your current page.

Comment: Hmmm. Basically, the external app should get the form data submitted and return the view with appropriate info. That bit is already done on the external app's part. Now I only have to come up with some solution that sends form data to the external app's controller action.

Comment: The iframe is essentially a new window, so you wont be able to send data to the main page hosting the frame. You could maybe use cookies or session data to communicate between these or something similar, or as stated above use partial views.